# Rails 4 multi-join, partially self-referential has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, self-join

*I know there are many similar questions out there, but I can't find any to match my particular situation, and quite frankly my brain is tying itself into knots trying to wrap my mind around this situation.  So any external insight will be greatly appreciated!*

I have `Users` and `Portfolios`.  `Portfolios` have a `creator`, who is a `User`.  **This is working fine.**

But `Portfolios` can also be shared between `Users`.  I'm modeling this with a `has_many_through` self-referential relationship. **This is where I'm having trouble.**

### **This is what I have, but it's not working.  Thoughts?**

**My Share model:** `/app/models/share.rb`

```
class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shared_by, class_name: 'User'  # the user who shared the portfolio
  belongs_to :shared_with, class_name: 'User'  # the user who was shared with
  belongs_to :portfolio  # the portfolio being shared
end
```

**My Shares table in the database:** (taken from `schema.rb`)

```
  create_table "shares", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "message"
    t.integer  "portfolio_id" # the id of the portfolio shared
    t.integer  "shared_by_id" # the id of the sharer (user)
    t.integer  "shared_with_id" # the id of the person shared with (user)
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**My User model:** `/app/models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 

  has_many :created_portfolios, foreign_key: 'creator_id', class_name: 'Portfolio'

  has_many :shares_by_me, foreign_key: 'shared_by', class_name: 'Share'
  has_many :shared_with_me, foreign_key: 'shared_with', class_name: 'Share'
  
  # portfolios the user has shared
  has_many :shared_portfolios, through: :shares_by_me, source: :portfolio, class_name: 'Portfolio'
  
  # portfolios that have been shared with the user
  has_many :portfolios_shared_with, through: :shared_with_me, source: :portfolio, class_name: 'Portfolio'

  ...
end
```

**My Portfolio model:** `/app/models/portfolio.rb`

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :shares

  # users this portfolio has been shared with
  has_many :shared_with, through: :shares, foreign_key: 'shared_with_id', class_name: 'User'
  # users that have shared this portfolio
  has_many :shared_by, through: :shares, foreign_key: 'shared_by_id', class_name: 'User'

  # the creator of the portfolio
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'

end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I'm going a little nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Oops.

I almost had it.  I just had a slight typo in my `user.rb` file:

Instead of:

```
has_many :shares_by_me, foreign_key: 'shared_by', class_name: 'Share'
```

I needed to have:

```
has_many :shares_by_me, foreign_key: 'shared_by_id', class_name: 'Share'
```

So many headaches over such a little thing!  But I guess that's how it always goes :)